# Master Kubernetes nodes offline GKE (mutliple clusters and projects)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This morning we noticed that all Kubernetes clusters in all projects ( 2 projects, 2 clusters per project ) showed unavailable / ERROR in the Google Cloud Console.
The dashboard shows no current issues: https://status.cloud.google.com/

It basically looks like the master nodes are down, the API does not respond and the clusters cannot be edited in the UI. Before the weekend everything was up and since at least yesterday evening they all show in red.

The deployed services fortunately respond, but we cannot manage the cluster in any way.
I reported it here too:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172841082

Did anyone else encounter this and is there any way to restart or trigger the master node to restart? I cannot edit the cluster so an upgrade is not possible either.
I read elsewhere that only SRE folks from Google can (re)start them.
It's beyond me how this can happen.

By the way, auto-repair is set to on and I followed the troubleshooting page, basically with all paths leading to : master node down, nothing to be done.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, or simply a SRE doing a start node action ;).

Comment: When everything goes down in such a fashion if there are no outages, the most likely culprit could be billing. Please check whether your billing is in order and check if emails were sent in that regards.

Comment: The above can easily be tested by trying to create a dummy vm on Compute engine. If you cannot create a VM then you know your issue is not strictly GKE.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @dany L, it was indeed a billing issue.
I'm surprised there is nothing like a message in the Cloud Console and one has to go to billing specifically to find out about this.
After billing was fixed, it took a few minutes while before the clusters were available, then everything looked back to normal.

Comment: If answer is based on someone else comment, it should be posted as Community Wiki. Also please accept it for better visibility for community.